# angularjs $http.jsonp success data access it elsewhere

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

How can I access the $scope or the data obtained from success in $http outside the `$http.jsonp()` request?

```
$http.jsonp('http://example.com/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.info1 = data.name;
        $scope.info2 = data.company;
    });

console.log("access it here outside: ",$scope.info1);
```

currently the console prints undefined.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't consider asynchronous ajax call to be work in synchronous way. You have to wait until that ajax/promise gets finished. Though don't use `.success`/`.error` they are deprecated, use `.then` instead to chain promise.

You must rely on the promise to promise gets `resolve`/`reject`.

**Code**

```
var promise = $http.jsonp('http://example.com/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
promise.then(function(response) {
    var data = response.data;
    $scope.info1 = data.name;
    $scope.info2 = data.company;
    console.log("access it here outside: ",$scope.info1);
    myOtherFunction($scope.info1);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: what should i use instead of success? could please provide the alternative way? thanks

Comment: it still doesn't get printed! i get undefined.

Comment: your console log is still INSIDE the `then`, i mean completely outside the code related to the `then`and `$http`, i want to use it in another function in the same controller.

Comment: You ahve to call that other dependant function from `.then` of current jsonp call

Comment: could you please give an example?

Comment: What example you need?

Comment: i want to use the `$scope.info1` in another function somewhere else in the controller.